# How do I sort a list of words by their letter endings?

Tags: python, sorting

How do I sort a list of strings by the last two characters

Input:

```
 ['abby', 'acts', 'aden', 'afro', 'agni', 'agra', 'aida', 'ainu', 'alba', 'aldo', 'alec', 'alex', 'alma', 'alpo', 'alps', 'alta', 'alva', 'amie', 'amos']
```

Output:

```
**aa
**ab
**ac
**ad
**ae
**af
**ag
**ah
**ai
**aj
**ak
**al
**am
**an
**ao
**ap
**aq
**ar
**as
**at
**au
**av
**aw
**ax
**ay
**az
etc...
**ba
**ca
**da
**ea
**fa
**ga
etc...
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is far too broad of a question right now.

Comment: For example you could write some code that does that for you. You're welcome! Now read a Python primer.

Comment: f=open('//#FILE.txt','r')
#create folder words4
words4 = []
#read words
for line in f.readlines():
    #strip /n off words
    line = line.strip()
    #make words all lower case
    line = line.lower()
    #if word is 4 letters add to words4 folder
    if len(line) == 4:

            words4.append(line)

# Remove duplicate words
for line in f.readlines():
    line = line.set()
    words4.append(line)

#sort lines into order using last two letters
for line in f.readlines():
       
    # This is where i need the line of code to be more specific...

Answer (score 2):

Use a function that takes a string and returns the last two character substring as the `key` in `sort` function.

```
data.sort(key= lambda x : x[-2:])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed where lambda becomes useful. If you don't understand lambda, let this example explain it for you:

```
l =  ['abby', 'acts', 'aden', 'afro', 'agni', 'agra', 'aida', 'ainu', 'alba', 'aldo', 'alec', 'alex', 'alma', 'alpo', 'alps', 'alta', 'alva', 'amie', 'amos']
```

Now you can do:

```
sorted(l, key = lambda x: x[-2:])
```

or the equivalent without lambda:

```
def func(x):
    return x[-2:]

sorted(l, key = func)
```

But with a function you can build in more logic too without losing **readability**.
For instance deciding what to do with words that are not of length 4.

```
def func(x):
    if len(x) == 4:
        return x[-2:]
    else:
        return ''
```

You also have the option to use:

1. sorted(list) # which creates a copy of the list that is sorted
2. list.sort() # which sorts the list itself

Comment: Anonta's solution has the advantage that if won't fail for one letter or  empty strings.

Comment: @kay that is true, I'll change to that. My example however is that there are more possibilities not mentioned in Anonta's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In one line you can try:

Take the advantage of tuple sorting trick :

```
list_1=['abby', 'acts', 'aden', 'afro', 'agni', 'agra', 'aida', 'ainu', 'alba', 'aldo', 'alec', 'alex', 'alma', 'alpo', 'alps',
 'alta', 'alva', 'amie', 'amos']


print([sub_item[1] for sub_item in sorted([(item[-2:],item) for item in list_1])])
```

output:

```
['alba', 'abby', 'aida', 'aldo', 'alec', 'aden', 'alex', 'amie', 'alma', 'agni', 'ainu', 'amos', 'alpo', 'alps', 'agra', 'afro', 'alta', 'acts', 'alva']
```

> Detailed solution:

above list comprehension is same as:

```
sub_list=[]
for item in list_1:
    sub_list.append((item[-2:],item))

final_list=[]
for sub_item in sorted(sub_list):

    final_list.append(sub_item[1])
print(final_list)
```